# How to install AMD GPU Driver 14.12 on Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: drivers, ati, radeon

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 14.10 on my Laptop, and I searched for hours on how to install AMD 14.12 driver without success. I have found the drivers on AMD's official site, but do not know how to install them.

http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Ubuntu%20x86%2064

Thanks to all who try to help me! :)

Have a nice day!

......................................

Just now I found that fglrx are remove if I install Wine..

Answer (score 0):

once you download the .deb package, just double click on package icon. It should install the related software.